# Argumento vacio. .Net y SQL

Tags: sql, .net

La siguien función me arroja el siguiente error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'El valor no puede ser nulo.
Nombre del parámetro: dataTable'
```

Ejecuté la Query, de forma directa en SQL y tuve respuesta. Por lo que no entiendo porque no trae los datos que necesito.

```
Private Sub txt_ppu_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt_ppu.TextChanged
    Dim cont_ As Integer = 0
    If Len(txt_ppu.Text) > 2 Then
        query_ = "SELECT Placa FROM Seremitt WHERE Placa LIKE '" + txt_ppu.Text + "%'"
        Dim dr As New SqlDataAdapter(query_, IConexion)
        dr.Fill(dt)

        MsgBox(dt.Rows.Count)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: que es dt?? ahi no esta definido... y ese es el error...

Comment: Gracias por esto, aclarando. Tengo inicializado el dt como publico al inicio.

Comment: ¡Cuidado con los ataques de _SQL injection_! ¿Qué pasa si `txt_ppu.Text` tiene valor `"; drop table Seremitt; --`?

Answer (score 2):

Este error se debe a que tu `DataTable` no está inicializado. Donde tengas definido `dt`, debes cambiarlo para que sea algo asi:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
```

Por cierto, nunca debes componer tu query mediante concatenación de strings, ya que así lo haces vulnerable a la [Inyección de SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL). Utiliza siempre parámetros:

```
query_ = "SELECT Placa FROM Seremitt WHERE Placa LIKE @placa"
Dim selectCommand AS SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query_, IConexion)
selectCommand.Parameters.Add("@placa", SqlDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = txt_ppu.Text + "%"
Dim dr As New SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand)
dr.Fill(dt)
```

Comment: Gracias por esto, aclarando. Tengo inicializado el dt como publico al inicio.

Public dt As New DataTable.

Comment: @Luippo Y en algun momento lo eliminas o igualas a `Nothing`? Intenta modificar tu código, define un nuevo datatable dentro de tu método, por ejemplo `Dim dt2 As New DataTable` y prueba a hacer `dr.Fill(dt2)` y mira si asi funciona